# JS Поиск совпадений в массиве

Tags: javascript, массивы, frontend

Подскажите пожалуйста, какой метод массива оптимально будет использовать для поиска нужного объекта внутри массива?

```
const arr = [
  {
    id: 1,
    name: 'Alex'
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    name: 'James'
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    name: 'Nick'
  }
];

const obj = {
    id: 2,
    name: 'James'
    };
```

Проверка на наличие объекта obj в массиве arr.
Можно вывести в консоль true, если есть совпадение или false, если нет.
Спасибо!

Comment: Вам стоит уточнить, будет ли это один и тот же объект или два разных объекта с идентичными ключами и значениями. В JS это не одно и то же.

Comment: если вы ищете по id, то например find: `arr.find( e => e.id === objId);`, что вернет вам соответствующий объект. https://learn.javascript.ru/array-methods